# Specifying Azure subscription when creating website

Tags: azure

I've been playing around with the new "Websites" feature of Azure (which I believe is still in beta), but I've run into a problem. I've got two subscriptions associated with my account - one for personal use, the other for my company. And of course, I'd like to be able to specify which subscription is used when I create a new website. But when I try to create a website, it always picks my second subscription, and never gives me a chance to specify which one I'd like to use. Nor can I figure out how to move the website to a different subscription after I've created it.

I've walked through this several times now, and I can't spot any place where I can specify which subscription to use. Is this just a beta glitch? Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same thing, called MS support.  Switch back to the standard portal to make this change.

To get to the old portal hover over the green "preview" button at the top.  This doesn't seem to work in Chrome for me, just IE.

Comment: Good tip about IE vs. Chrome :-). Unfortunately, the standard (Silverlight) portal seems to have started acting weird for me. Nothing happens when I click on the "Hosted Services, Storage Accounts & CDN" tab. Everything else works fine, but absolutely nothing happens when I click on that particular tab. I'm calling this one a bug.

Comment: I can't find Azure Websites in the Standard portal.  I think preview stuff is only in the Preview portal.  When creating an Azure Database in the Preview portal, there is an option to select the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Do take a look at my response on MSDN Forums for a similar question there: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurepurchasing/thread/d9624b03-1d6c-484a-9fa8-8548c35a9d4f/. Basically you would need to activate this feature for each subscription separately since it is in preview mode.